# How to prove the following inequality on a complete manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $u \in C^{1}(M)$, a ball$B(x,r)\subset M^{n}$, $(M^{n},g)$ is a complete manifold ,
$u_{B(x,r)} = \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}u dvol(y)$.

Try to prove there is a constant  $C(n)$,such that
\begin{equation*}
  |u(z)-u_{B(x,r)}|\leqslant C(n)\int_{B(x,r)}\frac{|\nabla u(y)|}{|z-y|^{n-1}}dvol(y)
\end{equation*}
If this can't be proved, how about the situation  when $r\rightarrow 0$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lvert z-y\rvert$?

Comment: $|x-y|$means the distance between z and y.

Comment: What is $X$? Have you proved this for $M=\Bbb R^n$ with the usual metric?

Comment: Yes.When $M=\mathbb{R}$ I can use linear transformation for  the variable.But for the manifold，things are different.Could you leave a e-mail address, I can take a picture for you，when  $M=\mathbb{R}^{n}$.  Forget about that X. It's a mistake. Sorry.